# How do I run more code in Twilio/Flask after enqueuing an incoming caller?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I want to have my Twilio/Flask app put an incoming caller on hold while I run more code to contact the person to connect them to.

The relevant part of my code:

```
@app.route('/ivr', methods=['POST'])
def welcome():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    with response.gather(
        num_digits=1, action=url_for('router'), method="POST"
    ) as g:
        g.say('if this is an emergency press 1, otherwise press 2')
    return twiml(response)

@app.route('/ivr/router', methods=['POST'])
def status_router():
    selected_option = request.form['Digits']
    if selected_option == '1':
        return redirect('/ivr/queue')

    elif selected option == '2':
        return redirect('/ivr/voicemail')

@app.route('/ivr/queue', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def queue_connect():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say("we are connecting you to our team")
    response.enqueue('otg')
    return twiml(response)

@app.route('/ivr/call_circle', methods=['POST'])
def call_circle():
    callCircle(on_call=True)
    return
```

The idea is to send the caller to `/ivr/queue` while I run `callCircle()` to contact someone. As is, I don't know how to get anything to run after returning the `queue_connect()` TWiML. I could run `callCircle()` as part of `/ivr/queue` but then the TWiML wouldn't run until the rest of the code ran, defeating the purpose of putting them on hold in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options here:

- You could switch from the queue approach to using Twilio conferences, i.e. in `queue_connect` dial the caller in a new conference instead and then connect webhooks via `statusCallback` and `statusCallbackEvent`. For a list of events see the [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent). I think relevant here is `join` which should fire immediately once the caller has been connected to the conference and thus solve your problem and just give you a hook to continue your business logic.
- You could use an asynchronous HTTP request in `queue_connect` before returning the TwiML to your user. Because effectively you don't care about the response to your `/ivr/call_circle` so you can just fire and forget. You could use [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) or similar.

Comment: got it working with requests-futures, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have the right approach here in my mind. I am guessing that `callCircle()` uses the [REST API to create a new call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#initiate-an-outbound-call-with-twilio)?

I would set up `queue_connect()`

```py
@app.route('/ivr/queue', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def queue_connect():
    callCircle(on_call=True)
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say("we are connecting you to our team")
    response.enqueue('otg')
    return twiml(response)
```

Note that when you create a call with the API it actually queues the call in Twilio's system internally. Meanwhile, your Flask endpoint then finishes processing and returns the [`<Enqueue>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) back to Twilio to send the caller into the queue.

The call is then placed, the callee's phone will ring, they choose to answer the call. All of this will take longer than enqueuing the incoming call. So when someone answers the phone the caller will be waiting in the queue to be connected.

If you are really worried about this order of operations, then I also agree with yvesonline's suggestion of using an asynchronous HTTP request.

Comment: I am using the API! but the problem here is `callCircle()` has a few different steps (it calls one person, and if they don't pick up, calls some more, etc), so setting and forgetting isn't an option

Comment: Can you share the code in `callCircle()` at all?

Comment: i actually got it working with requests-futures but thanks!

Comment: Great news! Glad you got it sorted.